# Connecting nodes to their next sibling in a tree

Tags: java, performance, binary-search-tree

I've tried to connect all the nodes in the tree to their immediate right siblings.

For example, root.nextSibling should be null. If root has 2 children "a" and "b", a.nextSibling should be "b" and b's should be null.

What I've done traversed the tree in level-order while setting the nextSibling pointers for all nodes in that level before moving down to the next level.

Please review the code and let me know if there is a better way of implementing this?

```
\* In class BinTree.java *\
public void connectSiblings() {
    Queue q = new LinkedList(); 
    if(root!= null) {
        q.add(root);
    }        
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
       Object[] a = q.toArray();
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
           BinTreeNode node = (BinTreeNode)q.remove();
           if(i == a.length-1) {
               ((BinTreeNode) a[i]).nextSibling = null;
           }
           else {
               ((BinTreeNode) a[i]).nextSibling = (BinTreeNode) a[i+1];
           } 
           if(node.visitLeftChild() != null) {
               q.add(node.visitLeftChild());
           }
           if(node.visitRightChild() != null) {
               q.add(node.visitRightChild());
           }             
       }     
    }
}



\* In class BinTreeNode.java *\
public BinTreeNode visitLeftChild() {
   if(this.leftChild != null) {
       return this.leftChild;
   } 
   return null;
}

\* In class BinTreeNode.java *\
public BinTreeNode visitRightChild() {
    if(this.rightChild != null) {
        return this.rightChild;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: By better you don't mean using a built in class which already does this ?

Comment: No.I dont mean that.Looking for something that will have better time complexity. Or something which achieves this recursively, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier accomplished by the BinTreeNode having a reference to its Parent.  Then Siblings are the Parent's Children Except `this`, with the special case of Root having no siblings easily determined by Parent being `null`.

Comment: When the tree has say 3 levels, how will this work? In a binary tree a node has strictly two children. If the 2nd level has 2 children and the leaf level has 4 children, 3 of them should point to the node to their right and the 4th one should point to null. When you have a reference to a parent you can set the references for the nodes of the same parent but how can the right child of a parent point to the left child of another parent?

Comment: Children of Parent's Siblings are Cousins.  To include cousins, adding the Parent's Siblings Children is an easy expansion of the above.